# Is it possible to build 32 bit on 64 bit machine

Tags: visual-c++

My development machine is Windows7, Visual Studio 2010. Can I build 32 bit configuration on Windows 7 machine?

Comment: Somewhat related topic: Can I still develop 32-bit applications using a 64-bit machine? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036380/can-i-still-develop-32-bit-applications-using-a-64-bit-machine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Just set your Platform Target under Project Properties > Build as x86

Comment: I want to build 32 bit build on 64 bit machine